# Data from Web form is not being added to Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am doing a simple form to be sent to my Firebase database but the database doesn't seem to be updating

database was updating when there was only 5 Var

double checked with the code went back to having only 5 var and it worked but i need all of these fields

firebase database is on test mode

Javascript :

```
var RRText = document.getElementById("RRField");
var CustAccText = document.getElementById("customerAccountField");
var ShipperNameText = document.getElementById("shipperName");
var CollectionAddressText = document.getElementById("collectionAddress");
var ShipmentOrgText = document.getElementById("shipmentOrigin");
var ShipmentDestText = document.getElementById("shipmentDest");
var ShipmentweightText = document.getElementById("shptWeight");
var ShipmentPiecesText = document.getElementById("shptPieces");
var ShipmentDimensionsText = document.getElementById("shipmentDimensions");
var ShptStackText = document.getElementById("shptStack");
var ChooseDeskText = document.getElementById("ChooseDesk");
var CommentText = document.getElementById("commentField");

function ActionData()
{

    // setting up values from Text Fields
    var RRValue = RRText.value;
    var CustAccountValue = CustAccText.value;
    var ShipperNameValue = ShipperNameText.value;
    var CollectionAddressValues = CollectionAddressText.value;
    var ShipmentOriginValues = ShipmentOrgText.value;
    var ShipmentDestValues = ShipmentDestText.value;
    var ShipmentweightValues = ShipmentweightText.value;
    var ShipmentPiecesValues = ShipmentPiecesText.value;
    var ShipmentDimensionsValues = ShipmentDimensionsText.value;
    var ShptStackValues = ShptStackText.value;
    var ChooseDeskValues = ChooseDeskText.value;
    var CommentValues = CommentText.value;

    var FirebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Requests").child(RRValue);

   FirebaseRef.child("Date").set(RRValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("RR").set(RRValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Customer Account").set(CustAccountValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Shipper Name").set(ShipperNameValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Collection Address").set(CollectionAddressValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Origin").set(ShipmentOriginValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Destination").set(ShipmentDestValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Weight").set(ShipmentweightValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Pieces").set(ShipmentPiecesValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Dimensions").set(ShipmentDimensionsValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Stack").set(ShptStackValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Desk").set(ChooseDeskValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Comment").set(CommentValues);

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
            <form action="" method="post" class="form-container" >

              <span id="close">x</span>

              <input name="RR" type="RRField" id="RRField" placeholder="RR Field" required>
              <p>Customer Details</p>
              <input onclick="sampleFunction()" type="number1" placeholder="Customer Account Number" name="customerAccountField" id="customerAccountField"required>
              <p>Shipper Details</p>
              <input type="number1" placeholder="Shipper Name" name="senderName" id="shipperName" required>
              <textarea name="collectionAddress" placeholder="Collection Address...?" id="collectionAddress"></textarea>
              <p>Shipment Details</p>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Origin" name="shptOrigin" id="shipmentOrigin" required>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Destination" name="shptDest" id="shipmentDest"required>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Weight" name="shptWeight" id="shptWeight" required>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Pieces" name="shptPieces" id="shptPieces" required>
              <input type="number1" placeholder="Enter Dimensions" name="shptDimensions" id="shipmentDimensions" required>
              <select id="soflow" placeholder="Choose Type" name="shptStack" id="shptStack" required>
                  <option value="Stackable">Stackable</option>
                  <option value="Nonstackable">Nonstackable</option>
                  </select>
              <select id="soflow" placeholder="Choose Desk" name="Desk" id="ChooseDesk" required>
                  <option value="KSA">KSA</option>
                  <option value="DHA">DHA</option>
                  <option value="RUH">RUH</option>
                  <option value="JED">JED</option>
                  </select>

              <p>Comment</p>
              <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Other Details...?" id="commentField"></textarea>
              <button id="submitBtn" onclick="ActionData()">Send Request</button>
            </form>
          </div>
```

Need the data typed in the input fields to be added/updated to firebase database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your two last 'selects' you define two 'id', erase the first one of each

Comment: You need to delete  id="soflow"
on both lines